# Extract value from an XML node using Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <user>
        <name>John</name>
    </user>
    <company>
        <name>MyCompany></name>
    </company>
</root>
```

I need to extract the value "MyCompany" (as a String value) from  node, and I don't know how to locate it. I don't need the other elements from the document. I extracted from the xml file the org.w3c.dom.Document instance.

Comment: it will be hard to parse it as it is not a valid `XML`, indeed you can only have one root element.

Comment: @Vladu correct your xml and use xPath queries to get  you desired node

Comment: once you will have a valid `XML`, you can use `XPATH` for this, more details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)

Comment: You can google it before asking (following the lemma: Google First, Ask later).... Example of how to do it: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaXML/article.html

Comment: Yup, I forgot to put the root element. My fault. I hope now it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)

Example:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                        "<user>\n" +
                        "     <name>John</name>\n" +
                        "</user>\n" +
                        "<company>\n" +
                        "     <name>MyCompany</name>\n" +
                        "</company>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml,"",Parser.xmlParser());
        for (Element e : doc.select("company")) {
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }
   }
}
```